# Meteor js: Create index in user collection

Tags: javascript, meteor

I create a user collection with a fullname field (i.e. Jose Osorio, Jose castro, John smith, Maria Smith), I need to create a search-bar to find registered users by their name or last name.

I.e. write in the search-bar jose and I want to see Jose Osorio and Jose castro.

I read about create Index in the database but it did not work or I did that wrong, what can i do to solve this?

Comment: Could you please post what you have tried exactly and how it went wrong?

Answer (score 12):

You can also use `rawCollection` like this:

```
Products.rawCollection().createIndex({
    "type": "text",
    "searchString": "text",
    "title": "text",
    "brand": "text",
    "description": "text"
}, { 
    "weights": {
        type: 5,
        brand: 4,
        title: 3,
        searchString: 3,
        description: 1
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution uses the most up-to-date method from Mongo (createIndex) and works within Meteor code -- it should be accepted!

Comment: Should this go right after the definition (`const collection = new Mongo.Collection('Products')`) of the collection or in `Meteor.startup`?

Answer (score 9):

To add the index :

```
Meteor.startup(function () {  
  Meteor.users._ensureIndex({ "fullname": 1});
});
```

and to make the picker, have a look at :
https://atmospherejs.com/fourq/typeahead

Comment: seems like a useful undocumented function.

Comment: _ensureIndex is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using e.g `db.books.createIndex( { "category": 1 } )` from the mongo shell.

Comment: Thanks worked for me, if you're using metor it's meteor mongo db.yourcollection.createIndex({"field": 1}, {unique: true})