# Meteor js: Create text index in collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I created a category collection with a name and description field. i.e

```
Categories = new Meteor.Collection('categories');

CategoriesSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    translation:{
        type: [Object]
    },
    "translation.$": {
        type: Object
    },
    "translation.$.name": {
        type: String
    },
    "translation.$.description": {
        type: String
    }
});

Categories.attachSchema( CategoriesSchema );
```

I need to create a text index to find categories by name or description.
i saw [Meteor js: Create index in user collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32550966/meteor-js-create-index-in-user-collection) but that not about my need i also tried

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    Categories._createIndex(
        { 'translation.$.name' : "text" },
        { 'translation.$.description' : "text" },
        { default_language: "english" }
    );
});
```

I read about create Index in the meteor but it did not work or I did that wrong? any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong API.

You should be calling `_ensureIndex` on your collection.